# Developed form of composition of polynomials in a finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, terminology, finite-fields

Let $q=p^k$ be a prime power. Any polynomial $a(x)$ with coefficients in the [finite field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) $\text{GF}(q)$ can be assimilated to a vector $a$ of $q-1$ elements $a_i\in\text{GF}(q)$, with (using the convention $x^0=1$ )
$$\begin{align}
a(x)&=\sum_{0\le i\lt q-1}a_i\cdot x^i\\
&=a_{q-2}\,x^{q-2}+a_{q-3}\,x^{q-3}+\ldots+a_1\,x+a_0\\
&=(\ldots(a_{q-2}\,x+a_{q-3})\ldots\,x+a_1)\,x+a_0
\end{align}$$

The set $K[x]$ of such polynomials is a [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) with addition $a+b$ and multiplication $a\cdot b$ of two polynomials such that
$$\begin{align}
(a+b)(x)&=\sum_{0\le i<q-1}(a_i+b_i)\,x^i\tag{1}\label{eq1}\\
(a\cdot b)(x)&=\sum_{0\le i<q-1}\biggl(\;\sum_{0\le j<q-1}a_j\cdot b_{(i-j\bmod(q-1))}\biggr)\,x^i\tag{2}\label{eq2}
\end{align}$$

Further, $K[x]$ is a [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) under function composition $\circ$, with $a\circ b$ defined by $(a\circ b)(x)=a(b(x))$. The law $\circ$ is right-[distributive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) with respect to polynomial addition and multiplication:
$$\begin{align}
\forall\,a,b,c\in K[x],\quad(a+b)\circ c&=(a\circ c)+(b\circ c)\\
(a\cdot b)\circ c&=(a\circ c)\cdot (b\circ c)\\
\end{align}$$

**What's an expression for the coefficients of $a\circ b$ from these of $a$ and $b$** (similar to $\eqref{eq1}$ and $\eqref{eq2}$ for $+$ and $\cdot$ )?
What's standard terminology for that operation on the vectors of coefficients?

Comment: What about polynomials of degree $q-1$ or higher?

Comment: I guess you make use of $x^{q-1}=1$ for each nonzero element $x$ of $GF(q)$.